# View a list of the listeners attached to a promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

Given a promise declared like this :

```
let myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  setTimeout(function(){
    resolve("Success!"); // Yay! Everything went well!
  }, 250);
});
```

Followed by

```
myPromise().then(() => { console.log("first then") });

myPromise().then(() => { console.log("second then") });
```

Is it possible to see the listeners attached to my promise before myPromise is executed ?

I wanted to inspect/debug the listeners attached to my promise, but it's not always clear what's listening.

Comment: A Promise cannot be resolved more than once, thus this question is irrelevant.  Plus your code isn't working (`myPromise` is not a function). You should, however, consider checking out `rxjs`

Comment: you can clobber the `then()` method with one that forks/logs/whatever and seamlessly calls the orig

Comment: There is no standard interface for enumerating promise `.then()` or `.catch()` handlers.  There may be some external promise libraries that allow some of this or you could patch over `Promise.prototype.then()` to log every time a listener is added.  Without capturing callstack info at the time it is called, I don't know what useful info you would be able to log and all it is passed is a function reference.

Comment: "before myPromise is executed" is not proper terminology as promise are not "executed".  Perhaps you meant "before the promise is resolved or rejected"?